# How to access localhost through NGROK tunnel running on Docker Windows?

Tags: docker, localhost, ngrok, hosts

I'm looking for a solution to be able to access services/ports running on my localhost on Windows through a NGROK TCP tunnel I established via Docker Windows running on the same machine. For a bit of background, I'm running this container: https://github.com/barbarbar338/ncfs. I confirmed that I can reach the Docker internal host, but I want to be able to forward that traffic to the localhost of Windows. I have a Minecraft server running on the localhost, and I'd like to connect to that server using the NGROK tunnel. I tried to run the Minecraft server in Docker and the tunnel works perfectly. I appreciate the help!